# Interfacing with fulcrum personal server

Tags: electrum-server

I'm trying to interface with my fulcrum personal server that's connected to my node but having issues getting a json response from my RPC call.

To enable RPC commands my understanding in the fulcrum.conf file I enabled:
admin = 8000

and then sending commands port 8000 doesnt work.  I'm able to connect via port 50002 but my json request is returning an empty response.  Any guidance would be helpful.  I realize this isn't technically related to bitcoin core.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling TCP over port 50001 with `tcp = 0.0.0.0:50001` in the `fulcrum.conf` file fixed the issue.

I removed `admin = 8000` in the `fulcrum.conf` file, as it is not needed.